# ¿Cómo personalizaría una tabla con css3 o html para que quede como en la ilustración?

Tags: html, css

Quisiera personalizar una tabla con `CSS3` que se vea como en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el código que estaría empleando para crearlo. Sin embargo, la última columna quisiera personalizarla de tal manera que quede expandida, como se muestra en la imagen. No sé si me explico.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tabla 0</th>
            <th>Tabla 1</th>
            <th>Tabla 2</th>
            <th>Tabla 3</th>
            <th>Tabla 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Tabla 0</th>
            <th>Tabla 1</th>
            <th>Tabla 2</th>
            <th>Tabla 3</th>
            <th>Tabla 4</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tabla 0</td>
            <td>Tabla 1</td>
            <td>Tabla 2</td>
            <td>Tabla 3</td>
            <td>Tabla 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sin más por el momento, eso es todo. De antemano muchas gracias por sus respuestas y buen día.

Comment: Mauro, estas usando algun frame, tipo bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se requiere `CSS` para lograrlo, con la maquetación `html` adecuada es suficiente. *El `CSS` del ejemplo lo uso para un propósito diferente.*

Puedes apoyarte con el uso de la propiedad `colspan` en la etiqueta `<td>` o `<th>` que necesites ampliar.

Como bonus te dejo un ejemplo ocupando dos columnas y dos filas combinando la propiedad `colspan` y `rowspan`

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
            <th>Head 4</th>
            <th>Head 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>1 columna</td>
            <td>1 columna</td>
            <td>1 columna</td>
            <td>1 columna</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td colspan="4">4 columnas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Row 3</td>
            <td>1 columna</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">2 columnas y 2 filas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td colspan="2">2 columnas</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Foot 1</th>
            <th>Foot 2</th>
            <th>Foot 3</th>
            <th>Foot 4</th>
            <th>Foot 5</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si usas el atributo colspan: `<td colspan="11">....</td>` 
El atributo colspan: Hara que la celda ocupe los cuadros que coloques. En este caso 11 celdas en una.

Comment: Ya pude hacer que las columnas se combinen, usando el colspan. Muchas gracias por el dato.